# Switch compiler on Matlab 2017a in Ubuntu OS

Tags: c++, matlab, ubuntu

I am running a script that needs a cpp compiler. I'm using MATLAB on both Windows and Ubuntu. On windows, with:

```
MEX configured to use 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' for C++ language compilation.
```

i have no problem.

On Ubuntu, i have:

```
MEX configured to use 'g++' for C++ language compilation.
```

and when i try to compile me .cpp files i get this error:

```
Error using mex
/home/christosandsoren/17gr10409/deformable_models/texture_functions/build_km_tree.cpp: In function ‘void mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)’:
/home/christosandsoren/17gr10409/deformable_models/texture_functions/build_km_tree.cpp:380:9: error: cannot convert ‘const size_t* {aka const long unsigned int*}’ to ‘const
int*’ in assignment
     dim = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
         ^
/home/christosandsoren/17gr10409/deformable_models/texture_functions/build_km_tree.cpp:402:68: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘const size_t* {aka const long unsigned
int*}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘mxArray* mxCreateNumericArray(size_t, const size_t*, mxClassID, mxComplexity)’
     plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(2, dtree, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
                                                                    ^


Error in compile_mex_functions (line 3)
mex build_km_tree.cpp % based on Euclidean distance
```

I installed mingw-w64, by `sudo apt-get install mingw-w64` but i still get the same result.

Comment: It seems that you on Windows use 32-bit (despite the MinGW64 name), and on Linux use 64-bit. Since `size_t` is either 32 or 64-bit wide, depending on the system.

Comment: You should define `dtree` as `size_t*` and not `int*`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
I did the change you suggested and i got rid of the last error. Though the :
`Error using mex
build_km_tree.cpp: In function ‘void mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)’:
build_km_tree.cpp:380:34: error: cannot convert ‘const size_t* {aka const long unsigned int*}’ to
‘const int*’ in assignment`

is still there...

In case you need it:
`void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
        int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])`

Comment: More code is needed. Otherwise I'm just guessing, a [MCVE]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mzg2hkx8nfjw6z/build_km_tree.cpp?dl=0
Is this better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you use `int` and not `mwSize` for you dimension arrays:

```
const int *dim; // image dimensinos
int dtree[2];   // tree dimensions
```

These should be:

```
const mwSize *dim; // image dimensinos
mwSize dtree[2];   // tree dimensions
```

The description from MathWorks is:

> mwSize is a type that represents size values, such as array dimensions. Use this function for cross-platform flexibility. By default, mwSize is equivalent to int in C.
>
> When using the mex -largeArrayDims switch, mwSize is equivalent to size_t in C.

So the issue is that on one platform it is legal to use `int*` and on others it could be `size_t*`. However, it **always** correct to use `mwSize*`, since this is the portable solution.

As a side note I would write the first line like this:

```
mwSize const* dim; // image dimensinos
```

This way is IMHO simpler to read, [link to examples](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations)

Answer (score 4):

As Jonas pointed out in the answer above, it is better to use mwSize.

The same problem might also be caused while shifting between 64 and 32 bit systems. [eg this thread](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/174281)

In that case you can also try compiling mex with 32-bit compatibility flag :

```
 mex -DMX_COMPAT_32 file.cpp
```

This solution worked in my case.

Comment: This solution works for whoever dont want to change anything, thanks for sharing